# Preserve original array order after being modified?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to fix my view to where the database has the naming conventions of the rows in the wrong format. I can't correct these conventions within the query itself as it would affect a lot of functionality within the website. Therefore, I decided to rename them correctly with JavaScript so they display with the right naming convention in the view.

To do this, I had to write my query where it returns a fictional array like so:

**Original Array**

`['Tree_Domestic', Rabbit, Unicorn, Cheetah_Domestic, Shark, Whale_Domestic]`

What I want is to scan the entire array and only find entries that **do not** have "_domestic" or "_international" and replace them with "_international". For example, [`Rabbit,Unicorn,Shark`] do not have _domestic nor do they have _international so I want them to be like so:
`[Rabbit_International,Unicorn_International,Shark_International]`

I managed to do this successfully but I ran into the last issue,

It modified the order of the array in alphabetical order and I don't want that. I want the array to look like this:

`['Tree_Domestic', Rabbit_International, Unicorn_International, Cheetah_Domestic, Shark_International, Whale_Domestic]`

The reason I need it to look like this is because in my query, I'm also counting the most popular rows and if I modified the array with my count, the count won't go into the correct order with the array items that were sorted with the modified array.

Here is my query:

```js
$sql = 'SELECT animals,
   COUNT(*)
   FROM fictional_signup
   WHERE usergroup NOT IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    GROUP BY popular
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC';
```

**Javascript**

```js
var renameLocations = [];

dataLabel = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;
dataCount = <?php echo json_encode($count) ?>;

for(t = 0; t < dataLabel.length; t++){
  if(dataLabel[t].includes('_Domestic') || dataLabel[t].includes('_International')){
    renameLocations.push(dataLabel[t]); 
  }
}
for(z = 0; z < dataLabel.length; z++){
  if(!dataLabel[z].includes('_Domestic') && !dataLabel[z].includes('_International')){
    renameLocations.push(dataLabel[z] + "_International"); 
  }
}

// Returns the correct naming conventions but the order is incorrect with the count.
console.log(renameLocations);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the original array into a new array.  Doing so will keep the elements in their original order.

```js
var originalArray = ['Tree_Domestic', 'Rabbit', 'Unicorn', 'Cheetah_Domestic', 'Shark', 'Whale_Domestic'];
var modifiedArray;

modifiedArray = originalArray.map(function(value, index){
  if (value.indexOf('_Domestic') < 0 && value.indexOf('_International') < 0) {
    return value +'_International';
  }
  
  return value;
});

console.log(modifiedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create a new array with modified entries.

```
/*
$locations = [
    'Tree_Domestic',
    'Rabbit',
    'Unicorn',
    'Cheetah_Domestic',
    'Shark',
    'Whale_Domestic'
]
*/
dataLabel = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>.map(
    // "e" represents each entry in the array, one at a time
    function(e){
        // if the entry ends with _Domestic or _International,
        // then just keep the value
        if (e.endsWith('_Domestic') || e.endsWith('_International'))
            return e;
        // otherwise, append "_International" to the entry and use that
        else
            return e + "_International";
    }
)
```

Produces:

```
[
    "Tree_Domestic",
    "Rabbit_International",
    "Unicorn_International",
    "Cheetah_Domestic",
    "Shark_International",
    "Whale_Domestic"
]
```

Comment: I got it thank you both of the answers achieved what I was looking for.